# How to combine two dataframes with different number of both rows and columns using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation, row

I have two data frames with different number of both rows and columns.
Some indices and columns are common.

df1

```
  A B C
a 1 0 0
b 2 3 4
c 4 5 6
```

df2

```
  A C D E
a 1 0 2 3
b 2 4 2 4
d 1 4 5 6
e 1 2 3 4
```

The result should be

```
  A  B  C  D  E
a 1  0  0  2  3
b 2  3  4  2  4
c 4  5  6  NA NA
d 1  NA 4  5  6
e 1  NA 2  3  4
```

I tried "join", "merge", and "concat" but it wasn't successful. Would you help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at `bind_rows` of `dplyr` package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html?highlight=combine_first#pandas.DataFrame.combine_first)

```
df = df1.combine_first(df2)
```

Result

```
   A    B  C    D    E
a  1  0.0  0  2.0  3.0
b  2  3.0  4  2.0  4.0
c  4  5.0  6  NaN  NaN
d  1  NaN  4  5.0  6.0
e  1  NaN  2  3.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do that without using `combine_first`

```
pd.concat([df.stack(), df1.stack()]).reset_index().drop_duplicates().pivot("level_0", "level_1", 0)
```

Results:

```
level_1    A    B    C    D    E
level_0
a        1.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  3.0
b        2.0  3.0  4.0  2.0  4.0
c        4.0  5.0  6.0  NaN  NaN
d        1.0  NaN  4.0  5.0  6.0
e        1.0  NaN  2.0  3.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
(pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), how='outer')
 .set_index('index').rename_axis(None))
```

Output:

```
   A    B  C    D    E
a  1  0.0  0  2.0  3.0
b  2  3.0  4  2.0  4.0
c  4  5.0  6  NaN  NaN
d  1  NaN  4  5.0  6.0
e  1  NaN  2  3.0  4.0
```