# How to replace values of a column of one dataframe with values of a clolumn of another dataframe based on their Indexes

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframes look like the following:

```
df_1=

Index        ID               Department
0            1895001           Media
1            1895001           Sales
2            1895001           HR
.
.
.
690          2060829           Marketing
941          1782054           Finance
952          1742360           Marketing
1060         1834992           Marketing
1064         1809653           Finance
```

```
df_2=

Index        ID               Department
690          2060829           Engineering
941          1782054           IT
952          1742360           Engineering
1060         1834992           Engineering
1064         1809653           IT
```

I have tried to merge them with this code `df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, left_index=True, right_index=True)` but it did not give me the result that i needed.
The follwing is what i excpect:

```
df = 

Index        ID               Department
0            1895001           Media
1            1895001           Sales
2            1895001           HR
.
.
.
690          2060829           Engineering
941          1782054           IT
952          1742360           Engineering
1060         1834992           Engineering
1064         1809653           IT
```

Comment: try `df_2.combine_first(df_1)`   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74787934/how-to-combine-two-dataframes-with-different-number-of-both-rows-and-columns-usi