# Replace rows in one data frame with rows from another

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks something like:

```
df1 =

name    code     country     type
---------------------------------
 ben     100          de        l
 mic     200          nl        s
 dan     NaN         NaN      NaN
 bro     NaN         NaN      NaN
```

I then have another data frame that looks like:

```
df2 =

name    code     country     type
---------------------------------
 dan     400          be        l
 bro     500          cz        m
```

So in this example `df1` has some rows with some missing values, or in some cases wrong values. However, luckily I have another data frame `df2` which has the correct values.

So basically, what I would like to do is move the rows from `df2` to `df1` based on the `name` column, i.e. the resulting data frame should look like:

```
df_final = 

name    code     country     type
---------------------------------
 ben     100          de        l
 mic     200          nl        s
 dan     400          be        l
 bro     500          cz        m
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine two dataframes with different number of both rows and columns using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74787934/how-to-combine-two-dataframes-with-different-number-of-both-rows-and-columns-usi)

Comment: `pd.concat([df2,df1]).groupby('name', as_index=False).first()`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with `overwrite=False` (to only update values that are NA in the original DataFrame):

```
df1.update(df2, overwrite=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just concat both datasets.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
```

This will basically 'stack' your datasets on top of each other.  You can then drop all nulls and duplicates.

```
df = df.dropna().drop_duplicates()
```